# How to fetch Comments from a Oracle 11g using JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, metadata

Is there a way we can fetch comments form Oracle using Java Code?I tried Using Describe but it did not work for JDBC(Java Code). Can u suggest some way?

Comment: The correct way would be to use the JDBC DatabaseMetaData. The result sets contain a REMARK column. (When `remarksReporting=true`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can running this query to get table's comment.

```
select comments from user_tab_comments where table_name = 'T';
```

If you want to get column's comment:

```
select comments from user_col_comments where table_name = 'T';
```

Comment: And thy `update user_tab_comments set comments = 'test' where table_name = 'T'` needs some privileges?

Answer (score 0):

the java code would be similar what you would be using with any normal query i.e by establishing a connection and then executing the query and using the above 2 statements provided  by Iswanto