# java fetching DataBase Column Comment

Tags: java

I am Using jdbc
I want to databse column comment,
is their any way to fetch database Column comment
Using ResultSetMetaData it does not show any option

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557564/how-to-fetch-comments-from-a-oracle-11g-using-jdbc)

Comment: JDBC's `ResultSetMetaData` does not provide an API to access column comments. You'll have to query it by yourself. What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this info from the ResultSet metadata. See ResultSetMetaData

e.g.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM TABLE2");
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
String name = rsmd.getColumnName(1);
```

and you can get the column name from there. If you do

```
select x as y from table
```

then rsmd.getColumnLabel() will get you the retrieved label name too. hope that this will help you ....